# Permission mix-up on Mint

Tags: permissions, screensaver, chown, xscreensaver

So recently I accidentally started changing all the permissions in root to my unprivileged account :(.
It happened because I was switching between users and shells and the directory changed to / without me noticing.
Luckily I had -c enabled so I realised there was something wrong quite quickly(just after the home dir).
I then ran `chown root:root -R (all files owned by me in /)`
Now I'm having problems with xscreensaver and su'ing reurns failed auth. I can still use sudo though.
Is there any maybe a list of permissions somewhere?
I'm running the latest Mint XFCE.

Comment: And you are running Mint or Ubuntu?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Mint. I updated the question

Comment: Well , since you recursively chowned everything, you also have chowned everything in your home . . . .Do `chown -R yourUsername:yourUsername /home/yourUsername` to get your stuff back to your ownership

Comment: @Serg The problem is that most of the root filesystem was owned by me instead of root. I was attempting to do `chown -R yourUsername:yourUsername ./` but I was in / not ~

Comment: Oh, I see.  Changing ownership of everything on the filesystem back to root user will be the easiest next to reinstalling. But there are many direcotries in files , such as /etc/shadow or /etc/mtab.fuselock that have different group ownership, so if you chown everything to root recursivelly you still have to go back and fix many other files.

Comment: @Serg Exactly. Do you know of a list somewhere, or should I just use another system and do a cp with the attributes only option?

Comment: Live USB is the best thing i can think of , unless you can find a friend who'll willing to let you know all the folder/file permissions on his/her server/desktop

Comment: This is a relatively new install. I have an old one on another hard drive in another computer so I could maybe rsync? Or otherwise just do a nfs mount?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the simplest method of fixing all the permissions.
https://serverfault.com/a/117149/191095

```
getfacl -R / > /root/perms.acl
setfacl --restore=/root/perms.acl
```

It works perfectly. Now my xscreensaver and logging in as root work again :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much an "+++ Out of Cheese Error. Redo From Start. +++" situation.

Lots of files down in the guts run as different users/groups and while *most* things can live as "root:root" if this is going to be a long running system you're better off backing up /home and repaving.

Alternatively find another computer, install virtual box, install mint, and then run:

find ./ | xargs ls -lth | awk ' { print $1"\t"$3":"$4"  "$NF } ' > /var/tmp/perms.

You should then be able to copy perms over to your mint computer, and write a script that reads that file and sets the right user/group ownership.

Actually, that would be a good penance as well as a useful technical exercise. :)